# Calling setState() with child functional component causes infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using [react-week-scheduler](https://github.com/remotelock/react-week-scheduler) to display a week calendar view on my page. This component is a functional child component to a class-based parent component. I would like the parent component to manage the `schedule` state for the events that show up on the calendar and pass it down to the child component as props.

The issue I'm facing is that every time I make an adjustment on the `TimeGrid` (by clicking and dragging out a new event block) and trigger my `handleGridChange` function to save that adjustment to the `schedule` state field, it results in an endless loop of state updating as `setState` causes the child `TimeGrid` component to update, thus triggering the `handleGridChange` function again, putting me into an endless loop.

The `TimeGrid` component works fine if I handle the `schedule` state directly on the child component and update it with a `useState` hook, but then the rest of my application doesn't have access to the `schedule` state. I have tried converting the `TimeGrid` to a class-based component, but then I run into other issues with `setState` as I don't think the component was designed to be used that way.

I'm pretty new/unfamiliar with react hooks so I feel like that might contribute to some, or even all, of this issue. It may also have something to do with the way the `TimeGrid` component is designed with `useEffect` constantly changing things when I set state, but I'm not sure and can't figure it out. Any insight would be very helpful.

My parent component looks something like this:

```
import TimeGrid from './TimeGrid';

class ScheduleView extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      schedule: [], // initially empty
    };
  )

  handleGridChange(newSchedule) {
    this.setState({
      schedule: newSchedule,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TimeGrid
        schedule={this.state.schedule}
        handleGridChange={this.handleGridChange.bind(this)}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

And my `TimeGrid` component looks like this:

```
function TimeGrid(props) {
  // const [schedule, setSchedule] = useState([]); // <-- managing state with this works fine, but then I don't have access to it outside this component

  // oldHandleGridChange(newSchedule) {
  //   setSchedule(newSchedule);
  // }

  return (
    <TimeGridScheduler
      schedule={props.schedule}
      onChange={props.handleGridChange}
    />
  );
}

export default TimeGrid;
```

Comment: bind the function on the constructor and then pass the function to Child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to bind it on constructor, when ever function binding is passed as props a new function will be created by which the props will signify a change triggering the render again

```
import TimeGrid from './TimeGrid';

class ScheduleView extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      schedule: [], // initially empty
    };
    this.handleGridChange = this.handleGridChange.bind(this);
  )

  handleGridChange(newSchedule) {
    this.setState({
      schedule: newSchedule,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TimeGrid
        schedule={this.state.schedule}
        handleGridChange={this.handleGridChange}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked! Why do I need to bind it on the constructor (why wasn't what I had working)? If you update your answer with an explanation, I'll accept it.

Comment: Updated with an explanation @McFizz

Answer (score 0):

Just you need to trigger the `onChange` event once. Or in short, you can bind the function using the fat arrow function ( => ).

```
import TimeGrid from './TimeGrid';

class ScheduleView extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      schedule: [], // initially empty
    };
  )

  handleGridChange = (newSchedule) => {
    this.setState({
      schedule: newSchedule,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TimeGrid
        schedule={this.state.schedule}
        handleGridChange={(e) => this.handleGridChange(e)} 
        /* or handleGridChange={ this.handleGridChange } */
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How is this different from my current implementation?

Comment: you are calling this.handleGridChange() on mounting of the component. Instead of you have to call the function on triggering some event i.e in this case this.handleGridChange()

Answer (score 0):

It is mostly because onChange function is triggered infinite time and you will need to add arrow operator over there.

This link might help you
[Prevent Infite loop](https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/why-does-my-code-cause-an-infinite-loop-and-how-do-i-fix-this-reactjs-solved/220053/10)

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead of your *`handleGridChange`* function

```
<TimeGrid
        schedule={this.state.schedule}
        handleGridChange={(newSchedule) => this.setState({schedule: newSchedule})}
/>
```

it'll work for sure.